# Django: Key error during migrations in Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am deploying my django web app to Google app engine. Deployed successfully. 
Now when i run `$ python manage.py makemigrations` there was an error due to this,

In my settings.py I have,

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

In my app.yaml I have,

```
env_variables:
    SECRET_KEY : 'my-secret-key-is-here'
```

The error I am getting is,

```
File "C:\Users\Bidhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

The error clearly is due to secret key not present in settings.py. How to solve this?

Note: If this question is asked before, I could not find it here. So it will be helpful to tag the question in comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app.yaml` file is used to set some configuration, like environment variables, for the deployed app, when it's running on Google infrastructure.

I believe you are running the `python manage.py makemigrations` command from your local computer, so you need to define your environment variable on your local machine:

```
set SECRET_KEY=your_secret_key
```

Comment: Right, I forget to add those in my env variable for local machine.